# Default Zone Confusion in Date Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I have a timestamp in milliseconds. eg:1394504624657L and using following code I'm converting it to Calender object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);
```

Above can be UTC/GMT. It represents Tuesday, March 11, 2014 2:23:44 AM GMT

What is the difference if i create the Calender object without the Zone. Also is this the correct way in java coding to create the Calender object.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference if i create the Calender object without the Zone.

According to the documentation of [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()), the default timezone is used if no argument is given (probably depending on the settings of your OS).

> Also is this the correct way in java coding to create the Calender object.

It depends on what you are trying to do. All `Calendar` factory methods are valid ways to create `Calendar` instances -- depending on the use case.

Comment: Thanks Robin, But here the problem is , from calender object when I return cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) , if the Calender object created by giving timezone like above it returns 2 which is correct. But if I remove the timeZone , it returns 7 for HOUR. That's why I'm confuse of whether its the correct way. My use case is user gives a timestamp in milliseconds and then return the Hour. I would be very much grateful if you can help me to resolve this confusion.

Comment: @user3919392 are you familiar with the concept of time zones? Let's assume you live in Pakistan. Then your local (and default) timezone is UTC+5. So if the timestamp is 2:00 in London (= UTC), it's 7:00 in Pakistan (= UTC+5). Both results are valid.

Comment: ok Robin let's say for Tuesday, March 11, 2014 2:23:44 AM GMT corresponding milliseconds value is  1394504624657L. And I want to get the correct hour of that which is 2. So how can I achieve this. Please forgive me I'm new to this Time Zone